# PHPUnit 5.7 successfully fails local tests, but in gitlab.ci the tests pass without failing the job

Tags: php, gitlab, phpunit, gitlab-ci

I have an error in my tests to really fail, because the reason for my question is to know why the test fails locally with success, however in gitlab ci the job does not fail, thus making the job pass completely.

If I execute the local instruction:

[image: Test fails in local]

But in gitlab ci, the test fails but does not give the error of failure and so the job completes successfully, as shown in the image below:

[image: Test in gitlab ci]

- PHP Version: 7.2
- PHPUnit Version: 5.7.27

How to fix this job failure error?

Comment: Can you check what the output of `echo $?` gives when u give it after the test command.

Comment: @Origin The output is returning equal to `0`, that is, execution success. Which is different when it returns ` event returned with error code XXX` when it fails.

Comment: Locally if you run the command with the output statement `echo $?` it returns `0` too.

The error is from PHPUnit not doing this stderr check, not gitlab ci

Comment: Thats why the gitlab job doesn't fail. Gitlab job fails if the exit code is a non zero value. Ideally i think they should be exiting with a non zero value.  Is there a way for you to check whether the test completed (eg: test report file is generated or not ) if so a workaround could be checking that and if its not present exit with a non zero value.